# Saving the order of associated records in a Rails has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-plugins, has-many-through

I'm working on a Rails plugin that includes a way to modify the order of associated records in a has_many :through association.  Say we have the following models:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists_songs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :songs, :through => :playlists_songs
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists_songs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :playlists, :through => :playlists_songs
end

class PlaylistsSong < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :playlist
  belongs_to :song
end
```

If we change the order of a Playlist's Songs (e.g. `@playlist.songs.rotate!`), Rails doesn't touch the records in the playlists_songs table (I'm using Rails 3.1), which makes sense.  I'd like to make any call to Playlist's songs= method save the order of the Songs, though, perhaps by either deleting the relevant existing rows in playlists_songs and creating new ones in the proper order (so that `:order => "id"` could be used when retrieving them) or by adding a sort:integer column to playlists_songs and updating those values accordingly.

I didn't see any callbacks (e.g. before_add) that would allow this.  In [ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionAssociation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb), the relevant methods seem to be [writer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L39), [replace](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L290), and [replace_records](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L457), but I'm lost on what the best next step would be.  Is there a way to extend or safely override one of these methods to allow for the functionality I'm seeking (preferably for only specific associations), or is there a different, better approach for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list)?  It's one of the most old-school of rails plugins, and is intended to handle this sort of problem.

Rather than sorting on `id`, it sorts on a positional column.  Then it's simply a matter of updating the position, rather than the messy business of changing the `id` or deleting/replacing records.

In your case, you'd simply add a `position` integer column to `PlayListSong`, then:

```
class PlayListSong
  acts_as_list :scope => :play_list_id
end
```

As you point out in the comments, the methods in `acts_as_list` work mostly on individual items in the list, and there's no "reorder" functionality out of the box.  I would not recommend tampering with `replace_records` to do this.  It would be cleaner and more explicit to write a method making use of the same position column as the plugin.  For example.

```
class PlayList
  # It makes sense for these methods to be on the association.  You might make it
  # work for #songs instead (as in your question), but the join table is what's
  # keeping the position.
  has_many :play_list_songs, ... do

    # I'm not sure what rotate! should do, so...

    # This first method makes use of acts_as_list's functionality
    #
    # This should take the last song and move it to the first, incrementing 
    # the position of all other songs, effectively rotating the list forward 
    # by 1 song.
    def rotate!
      last.move_to_top unless empty?
    end

    # this, on the other hand, would reorder given an array of play_list_songs.
    # 
    # Note: this is a rough (untested) idea and could/should be reworked for 
    # efficiency and safety. 
    def reorder!(reordered_songs)
      position = 0
      reordered_songs.each do |song|
        position += 1

        # Note: update_column is 3.1+, but I'm assuming you're using it, since
        # that was the source you linked to in your question
        find(song.id).update_column(:position, position)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: and here is an old railscast about acts_as_list: http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I had looked at acts_as_list before, and I just tried it out now.  It unfortunately doesn't fix the issue of the join model's records not being updated during, for example, a `@playlist.songs.rotate!`, though.  If Songs are added or removed from @playlist.songs, positions are updated, but if only the Songs' order is changed, nothing changes. 

This is with `acts_as_list :scope => :playlist_id` defined in PlaylistsSong.  If I'm missing another option, please let me know, but I didn't see anything in the source of acts_as_list that deals with the issue above.

Other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts on this; it's unfortunate that there isn't a way to preserve the order while still using `CollectionAssociation::writer`, but perhaps it's safer that way.  It seems like a `reorder!`-style method is probably the next best solution, but if anyone else sees this later on and has other thoughts on it, please feel free to share them.