# Rails: How to store custom order / rank of associations (postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Rails newbie having a question about storing the order of associations. Background is I'm thinking about building a super simple survey app for learning purposes. The idea is to have multiple surveys and corresponding questions.

Models are straightforward:

```
class Survey
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

My question now - where and how would you store the custom order / sequence of the questions in the survey? Questions may be moved around, added and removed and should retain answers from survey responses.

I was thinking about introducing a "rank_id" (inside the question or survey model?), or some kind of new question_list model (`survey has_one :question_list, has_many :questions through :question_list`). But even with the question_list model, I don't really know how to retain order. Googling led me to [Saving the order of associated records in a Rails has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721163/saving-the-order-of-associated-records-in-a-rails-has-many-through-association)
 and it recommends the [acts_as_list gem](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list), but that seems like too much for this use case?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: There is an *almost* standard gem in order to manage sorted records: https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list Otherwise you could add a `position` column and manage it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd recommend using [`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) - it makes reordering a breeze. It doesn't seem like overkill here, rather the correct scenario for it :)

You can then add a default order to the `Question` model, using: `default_scope { order(:rank_id) }`. This will ensure your questions are retrieved in the order expected.

The gem itself actually recommends adding the `order` directly to the association:

```
has_many :todo_items, -> { order(position: :asc) }
```

It also defaults to using a column named `position` instead of `rank_id`, though you can overwrite this. In your case, in the `Question` model:

```
acts_as_list scope: :survey, column: :rank_id
```

And in the `Survey` model:

```
 has_many :questions, -> { order(rank_id: :asc) }
```

Happy to expand on any of that if you need - let me know.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Was a bit wary of adding dependencies early on, didn't know acts_as_list was as "standard".

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help - I remember having the same dilemma, and coming across a number of edge cases and performance problems when going it alone. Hope this works out well!